# Advantage/Disadvantage of using Sidekiq in a different server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sidekiq, amazon-elasticache

We have a rails application.

```
Ruby 2.3
Rails 4.2.8
Sidekiq 5.2.5
Postgres
Redis 4.1
```

And production server is in AWS. We want to separate out Redis & Sidekiq on a different server.

What are the advantages & disadvantages if we separate ?

I have separated Redis to ElastiCache Redis. And have connected to our AWS EC2 server.
But for sidekiq, not sure to move to ElasticBeanstalk ?

Any suggestions ?